# Speedup counter game

Tags: performance, rust

I'm trying to solve a Rust algorithm question on hackerrank. My answer times out on some of the larger test cases. There are about 5 people who've completed it, so I believe it is possible and I assume they compile in release mode. Is there any speed-ups I'm missing?

The gist of the game is a counter (inp in main) is conditionally reduced and based on who can't reduce it any more, the winner is chosen.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let n: usize = read_one_line().
        trim().parse().unwrap();
    for _i in 0..n{
        let inp: u64 = read_one_line().
            trim().parse().unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", find_winner(inp)); 
    }
    return;
}

fn find_winner(mut n: u64) -> String{
    let mut win = 0;
    while n>1{
        if n.is_power_of_two(){
            n /= 2;
        }
        else{
            n -= n.next_power_of_two()/2;
        }
        win += 1;
    }
    let winner = 
        if win % 2 == 0{
            String::from("Richard")
        } else{
            String::from("Louise")
        };
    winner
}

fn read_one_line() -> String{
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read");
    input
}
```

Comment: Could you quote the relevant parts of the problem HR description, or add a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner loop can be replaced by a combination of builtin functions:

```
let win = if n > 0 {
    n.count_ones() + n.trailing_zeros() - 1
} else {
    0
};
```

Also, instead of allocating a string every time `find_winner` is called,
a string slice may be returned:

```
fn find_winner(n: u64) -> &'static str {
    let win = if n > 0 {
        n.count_ones() + n.trailing_zeros() - 1
    } else {
        0
    };

    if win % 2 == 0 {
        "Richard"
    } else{
        "Louise"
    }
}
```

Comment: You're solution worked! Can you explain the logic of how you figure out the winner (how does count_ones() + trailing_zeros()  - 1) get the winner. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding memory allocation can help speeding up the application.

At the moment, the `read_one_line` function is doing one memory allocation per call, which can be avoided if you supply the `String` as a `&mut` parameter:

```
fn read_one_line(input: &mut String) -> &str {
    io::stdin().read_line(input).expect("Failed to read");
    input 
}
```

Note how I also alter the return type to return a slice (which borrows `input`): further uses here do not need to modify the original string.

---

Another improvement is I/O. Rust is all about explicitness, and it means that `io::stdin()` is raw I/O: each call to `read_line` triggers interactions with the kernel.

You can (and should) instead used buffered I/O with `std::io::BufReader`. Build it once, then pass it as an argument:

```
fn read_one_line<'a, R>(reader: &mut R, input: &'a mut String) -> &'a str
    where R: io::BufRead
{
    reader.read_line(input).expect("Failed to read");
    input
}
```

Note:

- it's easier to make it generic (`R`) than to specify the exact type of `BufReader` :)
- annotating the lifetime is mandatory because the return type could borrow either parameter

---

Putting it altogether:

```
fn read_one_line<'a, R>(reader: &mut R, input: &'a mut String) -> &'a str
    where R: io::BufRead
{
    reader.read_line(input).expect("Failed to read");
    input
}

fn main() {
    let mut reader = io::BufReader::new(io::stdin());
    let mut input = String::new();

    let n: usize = read_one_line(&mut reader, &mut input).
        trim().parse().unwrap();

    for _i in 0..n{
        let inp: u64 = read_one_line(&mut reader, &mut input).
            trim().parse().unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", find_winner(inp)); 
    }
    return;
}
```

with the bigger win probably being I/O (might even be sufficient in itself).

Don't forget to also apply @John's advices, this way you'll be allocation-free in your main loop!

Comment: Thanks! the loop was the main time sink, but your solution helped too